# Question regarding GWP (Kesten-Stigum setup)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a GWP with $Z_0=1$ and mean of offspring distribution $m\in (1,\infty)$. Define $W_n=Z_n/m^n$ and denote its limit by $W$ (i.e. setup as in the Kesten-Stigum theorem). I already know that $\{W>0\} \subset \{Z_n \rightarrow \infty\}$, but I am not sure how to show the opposite, i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}(W>0 \vert Z_n \rightarrow \infty) = 1$$

How can one prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is indeed called Kesten-Stigum theorem. It holds (if and) only if the offspring distribution is L log L integrable (hence *integrable* is not enough). A simple approach to prove it is expanded in the paper *Conceptual Proofs of L log L Criteria* by Russell Lyons, Robin Pemantle and Yuval Peres, available [here](http://www.ima.umn.edu/preprints/January1994/1204.pdf).

Comment: I already had this theorem in mind, though I don't know, how the condition $\mathbb{E}[Z_1 \log(Z_1)]<\infty$ leads to this conditional a.s. statement. If I recall correctly, under the condition $\mathbb{E}[Z_1 \log(Z_1)]<\infty$, the statement is that $W_n \rightarrow W$ in $L^1$ and $\mathbb{E}[W]=1$, so nothing about a.s. convergence. Do I miss a major implication of the theorem?

Comment: Did you check the link in my answer?

Comment: Oh I see, so if I understand correctly, then $\mathbb{P}(W=0)=q$ is the key, since by conditioning on non-extinction, one gets the result I was looking for. Thanks!